# JQuery templates {{if}} statement doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-templates

It *will*, however, work in IE, or Firefox.  Any suggestions?

**Edit**: IRT Pointy's observation:  There were no errors of any kind.  This page simply did not render anything more than the html that was in the  section.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
        <script id="template" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
            <tr>                
                <td>${field1}</td>
                <td>
                    {{if field2 ==="hello" }}
                      <b>if statement</b>
                    {{else }}
                      <i>else statement</i>
                    {{/if }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = [
                        { field1: "yayayaya1", field2: "oyoyoyo1"},
                        { field1: "yayayaya2", field2: "hello"},
                        { field1: "yayayaya3", field2: "oyoyoyo3"}
                   ];               
        $(function() 
        {
            $("#template").tmpl(data).appendTo("#table1");
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="table1">
          <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>field1</th>
                <th>field2</th>
            </tr>            
        </thead> 
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens if you change that so that the expanded template is appended to the `<thead>` block, where it really belongs?

Comment: When I've used the jQuery templating in the past, I've noticed that templates can be sensitive to extra white space.  Try removing the extra spaces at the end of your if, else and /if statements.

Comment: Also, just saying that something "doesn't work" does not help people trying to diagnose the problem. Are there errors?  Does anything happen?  Does it look wrong? If so, how?  Etc etc.

Comment: @Rifk, your solution is the one. http://jsfiddle.net/yads/AWZLL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It didn't work in Firefox (3.6) either when I tried it. But changing `{{else }}` to `{{else}}` fixed the problem in both browsers.

Comment: it was the whitespace.  Awesome dude.